# Change input value loaded inside HTML Object Tag, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this very simple HTML webpage that loads another webpage using the HTML object tag, and I would like to know if it is possible to change the content of an input loaded inside the object tag.

My code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            function fill(){
                document.getElementById('uri').value = "hola";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="fill" onclick="fill()">Fill</button>
    <object style="width:800px;height:600px;" data="http://validator.w3.org/" />
</body>
```

Inside the loaded object, there's an input with id 'uri', I would like to change this value. The error give is "Cannot set property 'value' of null", this means javascript isn't seeing the input.

So, is there anyway this can be accomplished?

Comment: Where is the code where you are trying to change the value?

Comment: The button has an onclick function, which tries to set a value to the input loaded inside my object, but Pamblam answered my question, it seems like it can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<object>` does not have a "value" attribute. I can only assume you want to change the value of whatever is loaded into he object, which by the looks of it, is hosted on `validator.w3.org`.

Unless your website is validator.w3.org, you won't be able to do that. Javascript can only access the DOM of pages that are on the same domain. You won't be able to change the inputs on pages/objects loaded from other domains via frame/object/whatever.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought maybe I could do that since it is an input, which I can set value through my keyboard on the browser, I didn't know Javascript can only access the DOM on my same domain, oh well, thank you!